# How to prevent spliting table header and first row of the table

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp to create pdf file from html. I have a dynamic string that will occupy half to full page and a dynamic table after that. The problem is there is lot of space if i move the whole table to a new page sometimes and if i break the table the header alone is in one page and the rest of the content is in the next page sometimes.

I want to know if it is possible to make sure that the page break is not introduced between the table header and the first row of the table.

I am aware of how to do the following

- Prevent the whole table from splitting if there is not enough space in the page and move it to a new page by using

  KeepTogether = true
- Allow the table to split but prevent the row from splitting if there is not enough space by using

  KeepTogether = false;

  SplitRows = true;

  SplitLate = true;
- Repeat the table header if the table spans across multiple pages

But i don't want any of these methods. I want to allow the table to split but just not between the header and the first row or the first two rows otherwise.

Comment: you figured out how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution figured out: Used `KeepRowsTogether()`

Comment: Can you give some source code?  For me, calling KeepRowsTogether() doesn't do anything